# Solving ODE with unknown limits

Tags: matlab, ode

I'm trying to solve a system of ordinary differential equations from y_1 to y_2, say

```
G' = D
D' = f(y,G,D)
```

with the initial conditions

```
G(y_1) = 0
D(y_1) = 0
```

My problem is that I do not know y_1 and y_2, to counter for this I of course need two additional equations which is

```
F_1(y_1,y_2,G(y_2)) = 0
F_2(y_1,y_2,G(y_2)) = 0
```

So far I have tried to implement it using fsolve (i guess the new name is fzero) to find the zeros, then from the functions F_1 and F_2 i call the ode45 to solve from y_1 to y_2 in order to calculate the functions. However it does not work and I can not seem to find any mistakes. Therefore i looked for new methods/ideas and I found the method bvp4c, but I'm not sure whether i can use it in my case. Does anyone have experience with bvp4c and know whether and how I should use it, or do you have other ideas?
Any help is appreciated.

Code for reference:

```
function [Fval,sol,t,G] = EntrepreneurialFinanceNondiversifiableRisk
global sigma rf tau b epsilon gamma theta1 theta2 alpha ya K I taug mu eta...    
omega
sigma=0.2236; rf=0.03; tau=0.1129; b=0.85; epsilon=0.2; gamma=2;
theta1 = -0.704; alpha = 0.6; theta2=1.704; ya=0.1438; K=27; I = 10;
taug = 0.1; mu = 0.04; eta = 0.4; omega = 0.1;
tau = 0;

option = optimset('Display','iter');
sol = fsolve(@f,[0.1483,2.8],option);
Fval = f(sol);
[t,G] = solvediff(sol(1),sol(2));

function F = f(x)
yd = x(1);
yu = x(2);
global rf tau b theta1 alpha theta2 K I taug
Vstar =@ (y) (1-tau+tau*(1-theta1-(1-alpha)*(1-tau)* theta1/tau)^...
(1/theta1))*y/rf;
VstarPrime = (1-tau+tau*(1-theta1-(1-alpha)*(1-tau)...
*theta1/tau)^(1/theta1))*1/rf;
qbar =@(yd,yu) (yd^theta1-yd^theta2)/(yu^theta2*yd^theta1-yu^theta1*...
yd^theta2);
qunderbar =@ (yd,yu) (yu^theta2-yu^theta1)/(yu^theta2*yd^theta1-...
yu^theta1*yd^theta2);
A =@ (y) (1-tau)*(y/rf);
V = @(y,yd) A(y) + (tau * b)/rf * (1 - (y/yd)^(theta2)) - (1-alpha)*A(yd)*...
(y/yd)^(theta2); 
F0 =@ (yd,yu) b/rf-(b/rf-alpha*A(yd))*qunderbar(yd,yu)/(1-qbar(yd,yu));
[t,G] = solvediff(yd,yu);
F = zeros(2,1);

F(1) = Vstar(yu)-F0(yd,yu)-K-taug*(Vstar(yu)-K-I)-G(end,2);
F(2) = (1-taug)*VstarPrime-G(end,2);

function [t,G] = solvediff(yd,yu)
[t,G] = ode45(@diff,[yd,yu],[0,0]);
```

Comment: Could we take a look at the code you are using? What is the function you are trying to solve?

Comment: I have changed the description to now include the code. But I am curious how to solve this in general.

Comment: I would suggest an iterative procedure trying to find a convergence between ODE and algebraic equations involving ODE solutions and initial conditions. IN other word, set one solve another and vice versa.

Comment: But I can't split the two algebraic equations, so if I set one and solve for the other one I'm not sure that there exist any solution for that variable. Or have I misunderstood anything?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the domain of definition is big enough and you have good initial values, a Newton implementation with divided differences for the construction of the Jacobian looks like this:

```
h=1e-5

for k=1:10 do
    Fval = F(yd, yu)
    dFdyd = (F(yd+h, yu)-F(yd-h, yu))/(2*h)
    dFdyu = (F(yd, yu+h)-F(yd, yu-h))/(2*h)

    dF = [ dFdyd dFdyu ]

    ynext = [ yd; yu ] - dF^(-1)*Fval;

    yd = ynext(1); yu = ynext(2);

end
```

Comment: I really appreciate the answer, but this is what I am already doing. I am just using the build in solver in stead of implementing my own Newton method. A bit off topic, when I have to differentiate numerically I have always heard that you should use h = sqrt(eps), how do you choose your h?

Comment: That `h` is for simple forward or backward difference quotients. For the central difference quotient you get to take the third root. For a 4th order approximation, the 5th root etc. These are only guidelines, in the actual error you get the complexity of the function and the relations of the scales of the derivatives. More formulas and example at http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1214670/115115